# Copy object properties: reflection or serialization - which is faster?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have two objects of the same type and need to copy property values from one object to another. There are two options:

1. Use reflection, navigate through the properties of the first object and copy the values.
2. Serialize the first object and deserialize a copy.

Both work for my requirement, the question is which do I better use in the terms of speed (cost)?

**Example**

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Firsthand { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public int Age { get; set; } 
    public decimal Weight { get; set; } 
}
```

Need to copy property values from `Person p1` to `Person p2`.

For this simple sample - which method is faster?

**Update**

For serialization I use the ObjectCopier suggested here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

For reflection I use this code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo sourcePropertyInfo in copyFromObject.GetType().GetProperties())  
{
    PropertyInfo destPropertyInfo = copyToObject.GetType().GetProperty(sourcePropertyInfo.Name);

    destPropertyInfo.SetValue(
        copyToObject,
        sourcePropertyInfo.GetValue(copyFromObject, null),
        null);
}
```

Comment: How about autoMapper http://automapper.org/  or would just Clone() do the job?

Comment: Why can't yo do it with normal assignment?

Comment: @Miau, This seems to be a complex property copying system, thanks for the link, very interesting. But for my need currently I require it to be simple, so AutoMapper will be a canon for this case I think. But I will surely examine and use it for complex tasks.

Comment: @DavidKemp, since it must be a universal system which works for any supplied classes.

Comment: @net_prog so do you want a deep or shallow copy?

Comment: @DavidKemp, for my current task I need a shallow copy (just copy non-reference values).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to copy, and what kind of serializer you plan to use. Thing with serializers is, *some* of them might be actually using reflection as underlying mechanism of building objects.

**Edit #1:** As far as I know, `BinaryFormatter` used by your class does utilize reflection to do its work. So question is, can you write better (faster?) custom reflection code for your types than Microsoft did for general scenario?

**Edit #2:** Out of curiosity, I've run simple test. `BinaryFormatter` vs reflection in terms of performing *shallow copy*. Reflection code I used can be seen here:

```
var newPerson = Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();
var fields = newPerson.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public 
    | BindingFlags.Instance);
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    var value = field.GetValue(person);
    field.SetValue(newPerson, value);
}
```

What are the results compared to `ObjectCopier` class you're using? Reflection seems to perform **7 times faster** than serialization code. This however applies to `Person` class with **public fields**. For properties, difference is still noticable, but it's only 2 times faster.

I assume difference comes from the fact that `BinaryFormatter` needs to use streams, which introduce additional overhead. Yet this is just my assumption, which might be far from facts.

Source code for testing program I used can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/YG0E3HYd). Anybody is welcome to point flaws and possible problems with it :-)

---

*Sidenote*
As with all *"I was wondering..."* benchmarks, I suggest you take it with a grain of salt. Such optimizations should be only made when their performance actually becomes an issue.

Comment: I have simple classes with primitive types, such as int, string, etc... I use serializer suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp Types of the classes are supplied by external code.

Comment: @net_prog: check my edit. I've run simple test for your class using both methods.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I actually wanted the class to be with properties, not fields, I have corrected the sample. But even in this case reflection is faster as I can see.

Comment: If you specify `System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic` as the search options for `GetFields()`, it includes backing fields for all properties.

Answer (score 8):

Ultimately, general-purpose serializers (such as `BinaryFormatter`, via `ObjectCopier`) **are using reflection**. How *well* they use it depends on the specific serializer, but there is always extra overhead involved if you are serializing.

Since you only want a shallow copy, a tool like AutoMapper is the *most appropriate* tool here; again, it is using reflection (but I expect it is doing it "the right way", i.e. not via `GetValue()`/`SetValue()`), but it doesn't have the serialization costs.

In this scenario, serialization is overkill; AutoMapper is perfectly reasonable. If you wanted deep-clones, it gets trickier... serialization may start being tempting. I still probably wouldn't choose `BinaryFormatter` myself, but I'm very fussy about serialization ;p

It would of course be trivial to right some *basic* reflection that does the same via `GetValue()` etc, but that would be slow. Another interesting option here is that you can use the `Expression` API to create an object copier at runtime.... but... AutoMapper does everything you'd need here, so it seems redundant effort.

Answer (score 0):

Binary serialization is very fast I use it a lot for this kind of problem

[Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: For serialization I use the ObjectCopier from that thread, is it faster than reflection?

Comment: @net_prog how do you think `BinaryFormatter` (the serializer under `ObjectCopier`) gets its data? Hint: it starts with "r" and sounds like "deflection".

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying the properties during run time, reflection would be the answer. I would go for serialization if its not during run time.
[Serialization vs Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393084/xml-serialization-vs-reflection-in-c-sharp) look at this once.

Comment: If you know the properties of the object during run time, reflection would be waste of time, serialization would be the answer. But if you don't know the properties of the object during run time, reflection is the only solution i can think of.

Comment: If you know the properties, why would serialization suddenly be better than reflection? Not sure that makes sense...

Comment: because reflection is used when the type of object is not known during run time. If the type of object is already known, why to bother using reflection when serialization(binary serialization) is fast and easily achieved.

Comment: That makes no sense at all. Serialisation is going to involve reflection here; adding the actual encode/decode steps only adds work. For two reasonable implementations of a reflection-copier vs serialisation, and for a shallow copy, the reflection-copier is preferable in every way. Spoken as someone who knows as awful lot about both reflection and serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Copy(object copyToObject, object copyFromObject)
{
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    FieldInfo[] fields = copyFromObject.GetType().GetFields(flags);
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
    {
        BindingFlags bindFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic
            | BindingFlags.Static;
        FieldInfo field = copyFromObject.GetType().GetField(fields[i].Name, bindFlags);
        FieldInfo toField = copyToObject.GetType().GetField(fields[i].Name, bindFlags);
        if(field != null)
        {
            toField.SetValue(copyToObject, field.GetValue(copyFromObject));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code might answer the question. But you help the OP more if you explain what the code does and how it solves the question.